# How do I format a Decimal to a programatically controlled number of decimals in c#?

Tags: c#, string, formatting

How can I format a number to a fixed number of decimal places (keep trailing zeroes) where the number of places is specified by a variable?

e.g.

```
int x = 3;
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.2345M, x)); // 1.234 (good)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1M, x));      // 1   (would like 1.000)
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.2M, x));    // 1.2 (would like 1.200)
```

Note that since I want to control the number of places programatically, this string.Format won't work (surely I ought not generate the format string):

```
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Format("{0:0.000}", 1.2M));    // 1.200 (good)
```

Should I just include Microsoft.VisualBasic and use [FormatNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.formatnumber(VS.80).aspx)?

I'm hopefully missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
decimal x = 32.0040M;
string value = x.ToString("N" + 3 /* decimal places */); // 32.004
string value = x.ToString("N" + 2 /* decimal places */); // 32.00
// etc.
```

Hope this works for you.  See

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

for more information.  If you find the appending a little hacky try:

```
public static string ToRoundedString(this decimal d, int decimalPlaces) {
    return d.ToString("N" + decimalPlaces);
}
```

Then you can just call

```
decimal x = 32.0123M;
string value = x.ToRoundedString(3);  // 32.012;
```

Comment: How do I specify the number of decimals as a variable? I suppose I could do (1.2M).ToString("D" + x) but that seems a little hacky

Comment: Well you can always turn it in to an extension method.

Comment: Please note: the difference between "F" and "N": "N" will insert a thousands separator while "F" will not.

Answer (score 5):

Try this to dynamically create your own format string without having to use multiple steps.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(string.Format("{{0:0.{0}}}", new string('0', iPlaces)), dValue))
```

In steps

```
//Set the value to be shown
decimal dValue = 1.7733222345678M;

//Create number of decimal places
int iPlaces = 6;

//Create a custom format using the correct number of decimal places
string sFormat = string.Format("{{0:0.{0}}}", new string('0', iPlaces));

//Set the resultant string
string sResult = string.Format(sFormat, dValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

See these links for format string help:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

You want this:

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(1.2345M, x).ToString("F" + x.ToString()));
```

Additionally, the .ToString call will round for you if needed so you can skip the `Math.Round` call and just do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(1.2345M.ToString("F" + x.ToString()));
```

Comment: OK, so generating the format string ("F"+x.ToString()) is the trick, then? I assumed I was just missing a library. Thanks, Joel!

Comment: But... you described the exact same thing in the comments of the above answer as "hacky"?

Comment: <tounge in cheek>Once is a hack.  Twice is a best practice.</tounge in cheek>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should handle it:

```
int x = 3;
string format = "0:0.";
foreach (var i=0; i<x; i++)
    format += "0";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{" + format + "}", 1.2M));
```

Answer (score 0):

Method to do that:

```
private static string FormatDecimal(int places, decimal target)
        {
            string format = "{0:0." + string.Empty.PadLeft(places, '0') + "}";
            return string.Format(format, target); 
        }
```